# Calculating expectation of dependent variables

Tags: statistics, expected-value, independence, variance, covariance

Suppose $E[X] = 3$, $Var(X) = 1$, $E[Y] = 2$, $Var(Y) = \frac14$, $Corr(X,Y) = \frac12$

What is $E((X+2Y)^2)$?

> We can rewrite $E((X+2Y)^2)$ as $E(X^2+4XY+4Y^2)$
>
> We can solve for $E(X^2)$ using $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$. The same can be done for $E(Y^2)$
>
> This gives us $E[X^2] = 10$ and $E[Y^2] = \frac{17}4$
>
> We can compute $E[XY]$ through the expectation formula of covariance.
>
> $Corr(X,Y) = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} \rightarrow \frac12 = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{1\cdot\frac12} \rightarrow Cov(X,Y) = \frac14$
>
> $Cov(X,Y) = E[X,Y] - E[X]E[Y] \rightarrow \frac14 = E[X,Y] - 3 \cdot 2 \rightarrow E[X,Y] = \frac{25}4$
>
> $E[X^2] + E[4XY] + E[4Y^2] = 10 + 25 + 17 = 52$
>
> Do you see any problems with this computation?

Comment: You did not give us a value for $Var(y)$. I do not understand how you found that $E[Y^2] = \dfrac{17}{14}$.

Comment: sorry fixed it.

Comment: @shizzy I now agree with your calculations of $E[Y^2] = \dfrac{17}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I compute $E[XY]$.
$$ \rho = \dfrac{ cov(X,Y) }{ \sigma_x \sigma_y } $$
$$ \sigma_x = 1 $$
$$ \sigma_y = \dfrac{1}{2} $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{ cov(X,Y) }{ \dfrac{1}{2} } $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{ cov(X,Y) }{ \dfrac{1}{2} } $$
$$ cov(X,Y) = \dfrac{1}{4} $$
$$ cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{4} = E[XY] - 3(2) $$
$$ E[XY]  = \dfrac{25}{4} $$

I now agree with your answer.

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong, I used variance rather than standard deviation to compute correlation. However, I think you standard deviation of why should be 1/2. I believe $E[XY] = \frac{25}4$

Comment: @shrizzy I do not understand this:  However, I think you standard deviation of why should be 1/2. Perhaps there is a grammatical error. Not sure.

Comment: how do you tag users? And definitely a grammatical error, sorry. Correction: I believe standard deviation of y is $\frac12$ not $\sqrt2$

Comment: @shrizzy  You are right, I will fix my post.

Comment: @shrizzy to tag a user, you  put an @ sign followed by his/her id  in the start of the comment. I have updated my answer. However, we still disagree. If  you  feel your answer is wrong, please tell me where I went wrong,.

Comment: Thanks @Bob, I still disagree with your computation of your covariance. If $\frac12 = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\frac12}$ then $Cov(X,Y) = \frac14$

Comment: @shrizzy You ar3e right about $cov(X,Y)$ and I will fix my post.

Comment: @shrizzy I have updated my calculations but we still disagree. Please tell me where you think I am wrong, I do understand how  you  got $E[XY] = \dfrac{49}{8}$ .

Comment: I have also updated my computation. I think we still disagree; in your second to last line it looks like you have $E[X] = 1$, but it was given to be $3$

Comment: @shrizzy I now agree with your answer. Can you now accept my answer